# Make the column widths wider in a datatable that is filled by a dataadapter

Tags: c#, .net, database, oledb

I am using an OleDbDataAdapter to fill a DataSet

```
            adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cn);
            adap.Fill(ds);
```

The code works.  But the email column is too narrow.  Some of the emails are chopped off.  How do I get this code to widen the email column?

Comment: Can I "sample" the data somehow and then widen the columns and then requery again?

Comment: What data type is the e-mail field in the DataTable inside your data set ?

Comment: Can you confirm the emails in the database are complete?

Comment: The datafile is a Goldmine data file.  In goldmine, you can see the entire email address.  But when I pull the data through the code in .NEt, it's chopped off.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the e-mails are getting cut when you call Fill I would say the problem is in the database table structure or in the select not int .net implementation.